# Why doesn't DumpSave work for elements created within a local notebook context?

Tags: import, variable-definitions, contexts

I recently noticed that when dealing with notebooks with local context, I cannot successfully `DumpSave` variables, or, rather, when I call `Get` on the non-empty .mx files, the notebook does not recognize the variables.

As a test, I created two notebooks, one with a global context and the other with a local context, that is, for the latter notebook, I ran the command:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext->Notebook];
```

In both notebooks, I defined variables that contained a list of points from a standard `NormalDistribution` and plotted them using `ListPlot`. I used

```
DumpSave["filename.mx", {datavariable,plotvariable}];
```

to preserve both the data and plot. Long story short, after I save and close both notebooks and restart *Mathematica* , neither notebook recognizes the variables used for the data or plot, but after using `Get` in the global notebook, the notebook does recognize the old variables.

Furthermore, when I run a `DumpSave` command from the 'local' notebook that saves the entire context, i.e. `DumpSave["filename.mx", Evaluate@Context[]]`, I *do* get back the definitions. This doesn't solve my problem though, as I want to preserve only a few variables in the code that I am working on: saving the entire context, or, more specifically, all of the definitions associated with the context, would require too much memory for an application I have in mind.

Are there any solutions using `DumpSave` or should I resort to other methods?

Update, I've pasted the exact code below:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook];
distribution = NormalDistribution[]; 
thedata = RandomVariate[distribution, 1000]; 
theplot = ListPlot@thedata; 
DumpSave["test2.mx", {thedata, theplot}];
```

Comment: hm, works for me. Perhaps you could show the actual code?

Comment: @ruebenko, here is the code that isn't working for me:

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook];

distribution = NormalDistribution[];
thedata = RandomVariate[distribution, 1000];
theplot = ListPlot@thedata;

DumpSave["test2.mx", {thedata, theplot}];`

When I close the notebook, and Mathematica, then relaunch everything and call `Get` on the test2.mx file, it doesn't recognize `thedata` or `theplot`

Comment: you may want to post the code into the question; I think it's an integral part of it and it spares people the time to think of an example.

Answer (score 13):

When you use `DumpSave`, it stores the expression in `` Notebook$xyz`thedata `` where the `$xyz` part is a unique context for that notebook. When you load the file using `Get`, it restores the expression to the variable in *that* context.

However, there is no guarantee that your notebook will have the same unique context in two different sessions. Your new `thedata` might actually be `` Notebook$abc`thedata ``, but your data is in `` Notebook$xyz`thedata ``, which is why you don't "see" it (but it's there if you access it with the full context).

A better alternative would be to use `Import/Export` to save your `.mx` files as I [show in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25042/5). This way, the variable name is not stored, and thus won't be loaded into an arbitrary context. You can easily assign the data to a new variable in your current context.

Comment: +1. A side note is that `Import / Export` can be much slower than `DumpSave / Get` for `.mx` files (at least IIRC), so everything comes at a price. This may or may not matter, depending on whether or not the problem is IO-bound. The natural way for `.mx` files to work seems to attach values to some symbols.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works as expected, but perhaps the issue that not the proper context is used to retrieve the data:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CellContext -> Notebook]; distribution = 
 NormalDistribution[]; thedata = 
 RandomVariate[distribution, 1000]; theplot = 
 ListPlot@thedata; DumpSave["test2.mx", {thedata, theplot}];
Context[thedata]
(*"Notebook$$19$563288`" *)
```

In the newly opened notebook:

```
Get["test2.mx"]
Notebook$$19$563288`thedata
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help--I've posted the code in the question, as per your recommendation.

I also get the right context, but the variable `thedata` is itself empty; and I'm still unsure as to why. I.e. evaluating the cell containing only
`thedata`
I get back "thedata," not the 1000 values that were stored in `thedata` previously.

Answer (score 0):

Give the variable an explicit context as follows:

```
Module[{locImport,locFinishTime,locOutputFileName},
..
.
Greg`locExtractor=gHistDataComTickExtractor@locImport;

locOutputFileName=
"C:\\HistDataCom\\mathAUDUSD\\myAUDUSDmathByTick201512.mx";

DumpSave[locOutputFileName,Greg`locExtractor]

.
.]
```

You can retrieve the DumpSave as follows:

```
Get["C:\\HistDataCom\\mathAUDUSD\\myAUDUSDmathByTick201512.mx"]

Evaluate@Greg`locExtractor[[1]]
(* {3.65792*10^9, {0.72616, 0.72622}} *)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)