# How to find variables set through Get["/some/path/dump.mx"]?

Tags: contexts, variable

(**NB:** I could not find any good tags for this post.  Please feel free to add better ones.)

---

Suppose that the file `/some/path/dump.mx` was generated during an earlier *Mathematica* session by evaluating an expression of the form

```
DumpSave["/some/path/dump.mx", ...]
```

...for some argument `...` unknown to us.

---

**Q:** How can I find out which variables were set (or re-set) as a result of evaluating

```
Get["/some/path/dump.mx"];
```

...in my current *Mathematica* session?

Comment: How about https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25027/5478?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can also `Export` to the `.mx` format. If you use this method, then only the data will be saved, but any definitions. I much prefer this way.  I can simply re-`Import` and assign to whatever variable name I prefer.  If I want to save several pieces of data, and even give them names, then I use an association (or rule list in earlier versions).

Comment: @Szabolcs: `Export`/`Import` does seem like the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25027/1364)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short summary**

In your current Mathematica session, you can easily track creation of *new* symbols. There is however no simple way to track *updating* of symbols. As a workaround you can start a fresh kernel, load MX file there and track new symbols. This may give you some idea how given MX file will affect your current Mathematica session.

Methods to track *new* symbols defined by MX file can be found in the following question:

[DumpSave for the forgetful](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25027)

**Update:** I have moved some part of my answer from here to [DumpSave for the forgetful](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25027), because that question is considered canonical.

Comment: you might want to mention that by using `Off[General::stop]` you can show all messages for case 2, which probably makes that approach much more valuable...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thank you! I have included this hint into the answer.

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate but I see that you have since extended your answer.  Do you feel that my action was incorrect?  If this question is different from the other one can you edit it to make that more clear?  If it is not what do you think of *merging* this question into that one which will move your answer to that question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I have noticed the duplicate notice only after I finished updating. I think it is a good idea to merge these questions. I will need to change some sentences after the merge is complete.

Comment: I'll come back to this tomorrow.  A merge is irreversible so it must be approached with care.  Nevertheless I favor having all answers in one place when it is truly applicable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have moved/rewritten the relevant part of this answer into a full answer for DumpSave for the forgetful.

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't help you with past uses of [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave) to store variables, but rather it offers an alternative. One obvious way to store a variable to be retrieved later is to use [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put), as in:

```
m = RandomReal[1, {1000,1000}];

Put[m, "matrix.m"]; //AbsoluteTiming

stored = Get["matrix.m"]; //AbsoluteTiming

m === stored
```

> {2.22504, Null}
>
> {1.40961, Null}
>
> True

As the timing shows, this method is rather slow. It also has an issue where some objects change when run through this [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put)/[`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get) round trip. An alternative that I like is to define new functions, `PutMX` and `GetMX` (note that this can be made more robust by using a package):

```
PutMX[expr_, file_] := Block[{res=expr}, DumpSave[file, res]]
GetMX[file_] := Block[{res}, Get[file]; res]
```

As you can see, `PutMX` and `GetMX` use [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave) under the hood, but in such a way that they mimic [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put) and [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get). As an example:

```
PutMX[m, "matrix.mx"]; //AbsoluteTiming

stored = GetMX["matrix.mx"]; //AbsoluteTiming

m === stored
```

> {0.015008, Null}
>
> {0.005111, Null}
>
> True

There have been some earlier suggestions to use `Export[file, expr, "MX"]` and `Import[file]` instead, but this approach is quite a bit slower, due to overhead in the [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import)/[`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export) framework. For instance:

```
Export["matrix2.mx", m, "MX"]; //AbsoluteTiming

stored = Import["matrix2.mx"]; //AbsoluteTiming

m === stored
```

> {0.07974, Null}
>
> {0.055974, Null}
>
> True

As you can see, `PutMX`/`GetMX` are quite a bit faster.

Comment: The problem is that files saved with `PutMX` will only be compatible with `GetMX` but not `Import`.  So I looked up what `Import`/`Export` do with MX.  They use the same method that you show here: assign to a symbol and `DumpSave`, but they also wrap the expression with `HoldComplete`.  The symbol used is ``System`Private`ConvertersPrivateDumpSymbol``.  If you also use this symbol instead of `res` (and wrap with `HoldComplete`), you could make `PutMX` compatible with `Import`.

Comment: What is disappointing is that `Import`/`Export` do not use `Block`. Instead, `Export` just sets a variable and leaves it like that to consume memory ... it gets cleared only when `Import` is used.

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed after `Export` in MX, the symbol ``System`Private`ConvertersPrivateDumpSymbol`` retains a copy of the exported variable in memory. This should probably be reported.

Comment: @Shadowray OK, I reported it. I do not know if it will get fixed because it is such a minor issue.

Comment: Thank you @Szabolcs. Leaks like this are hard to notice but they can sometimes lead to unexpected memory and performance issues.