# Getting variables from MX file

Tags: import

I have saved a number of variables via `DumpSave` to a `MX` `file` called `file.mx`.

To read the file I have used: `Get["file.mx"]`.

**How can I find out what the variable names are that are contained in `file.mx` inside of a notebook file which already contains other variables?**

I have read the I can call e.g. `` Names["Global`*"] ``, but then all variables are listed.

Comment: Can you create a new notebook with another kernel and use `Get["file.mx"]` and ``Names["Global`*"]`` there?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to find variables set through Get?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144937/47416) and [DumpSave for the forgetful](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25027/).

Comment: Use @Shadowray suggestion, just compare ``Names["Global`*"]`` before and after `Get`.