# Question regarding MX files

Tags: export, import

Example:

I save data to a `MX` file, like:

```
a=Range[100];
b=Range[1000];

Export["data.mx", {a,b}, "MX"];
```

Can I after importing the data:

```
data = Import["data.mx", "MX"];
```

also retrieve the names of the variables `a,b`?

Comment: related: [DumpSave for the forgetful](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25027/5478)

Comment: great link, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because those names were never saved into the file.

If you want the names saved too, you can use `DumpSave` instead of `Export` for saving, and `Get` instead of `Import` for loading.  In this case, `a` and `b` will be overwritten upon `Get`.  I do not like this method because I need to remember those names, and because I consider overwriting dangerous.

Personally I would export an association instead of a list:

```
<|"a" -> a, "b" -> b|>
```

This way I can make the structure of the data self-explanatory.

Comment: Could I do this: `Export["data.mx", <|"a" -> a, "b" -> b|>, "MX"];`? and reading would be: `data = Import["data.mx"]`? After reading how do I assign `a=...` and `b=...`?

Comment: @lio Yes, that is what I meant I would do.  But the whole reason why I suggested associations was to avoid assigning. If you want to assign `a` and `b` after reading, then I suggest you use `DumpSave`/`Get`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ...

Comment: @lio To be fair, you *can* set values based on an association, but it requires something a bit more advanced: `setName[name_String, value_] := 
 ToExpression[name, InputForm, Function[s, s = value, HoldAll]]`  Now `setName["a", 1]` sets the value of `a` to `1`. So you can do `KeyValueMap[setName, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>]` to set `a` to `1` and `b` to `2`.