# Can I see a list of saved objects?

Tags: save

I created some functions in mathematica and saved them via `Save["filename",symbol]` It works just fine and loads the functions in whatever notebook I want them and I don't have to specify folder or package. Is there a way to see a list of saved objects? Are they saved in human readable file?

In the future I plan to use packages but now I have many global variables and packages are not comfortable with that.

Comment: Is that enough: `FilePrint@"filename"` or do you want only a list of symbols?

Comment: I just need a list of objects to keep track of what I can use in my notebooks.

Comment: There is no direct method so I'd use this tip: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145684/5478, take a look at linked answers too